# My ISP has me on a static IP address, but I'm sharing my connection. What IP address should I provide for Remote login?

Tags: vpn, ip, remote, desktop

The company I work for wants to set me up with Remote Desktop access to one of their servers.

My ISP has assigned me a static IP address; however at home I have multiple machines sharing the Internet through an ADSL modem/wireless router.

If I provide the company with the static IP that my ISP assigned me, will I be able to log in through any one of those machines?

Or will I need some special set up on either a machine or the router, to make it all work?

Answer (score 8):

The IP address your ISP gave you is the one your company will see, and the one they will need to configure.  Because you are running a NAT router, any of the computers sharing that IP address will be able to connect.

If you don't know your public IP address, you can visit whatismyip.com and suffer their advertising, or you can ask Wolfram|Alpha the question: "[what is my ip?](http://www02.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=what+is+my+ip%3F)"

Comment: or you can just go to http://whatismyip.com/

Comment: There are two typesof NAT. The NAT you need to use is DNAT - destination NAT, also known as port forwarding and in my own  modem its called a virtual host/server.

Answer (score 0):

Your ADSL router will be using [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) to assign all the machines on your local network a private IP address range. Because of this you will need to configure your router to forward port `3389` to the machine you want to Remote Desktop to.

Comment: Yes, now I understand what needs to be done. Thanks!

Comment: Nonsense, no port forwarding is needed since the Remote Desktop on the company's server will be accessed *from* the ADSL router. The way I read his question, he simply needs to determine his public ip address so the sysadmins at his company can allow his IP through their firewall.

Answer (score 0):

A helpfull website to correctly determine where you appear to be coming from (your IP address) to other people - ie websites etc is [WhatismyIP](http://www.whatismyip.com)

This was already mentioned above I just realised.

You will also most likely need to forward the Remote Desktop port (3389) to the machine you need to control. A quick guide on port forwarding can be found:

[Port Forward](http://portforward.com/)